# Any notes or rules for naming ruby gems with '-' or '_'?

Tags: ruby, namespaces, rubygems

When you create a ruby gem and name it, are you paying some attentions to name with **'-' or '_'** ?  Are there any differences to use between '-' and '_'?

```
$ gem list|egrep "\-|_"
actionmailer-with-request (0.4.0, 0.3.0)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.2, 0.0.3)
activerecord-import (0.3.1)
:
:
```

I feel there are some rules but I am not sure clearly at this moment. I would like to take a learn some rules or guidances if they exist. And I want to take a look at the code of some gems (near-)perfectly compliant with the roles if you know some gems named with '-' or '_', please give some answers as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are clearly examples of gems that don't follow any convention. The convention I have come to like the best is using `-` to denote a namespace (`::`) boundary and `_` as a word separator within a class name.

Examples:

```
| Main Class        | Gem Name          | require           |
|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
| Redis             | redis             | redis             |
| Redis::Namespace  | redis-namespace   | redis/namespace   |
| Redis::NativeHash | redis-native_hash | redis/native_hash |
```

Comment: The examples you noted above make sense for me to learn the differences in case of use of '-' & '_' in terms of ruby gems. Thanks Carl!